# How to make "connection is secure" message appear on purpose for certificate

Tags: javascript, html, css

When the website is under HTTPS, the "connection is secured" section won't appear unless the user clicks on the safety lock. Is it possible to make the "Connection is secure" section appear on purpose with some codes, like HTML, JS, or something else without the user clicking on it? I think I have seen some web pages doing that.

I have a section in my webpage where the user enters their credit card info, so I am trying to implement a little remainder for them.

[image]

Comment: No it's not possible from code run in window context. That would be completely annoying if any site could do that. What purpose would it serve? The lock icon already lets user know if page is on secure connection

Comment: Could it be just a JS/static image that mimics the appearance for example purpose?

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is not possible since it would require code from within the actual browser frame to interact with the browser window itself. There is absolutely no reason to ever do what you are attempting to do anyway.

The only methods that do exist would just scream malicious intent.

Answer (score 0):

You can´t solve this with code.
I think you looked for an [extended validation ssl certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate).

[example image of extended validation ssl certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frr8Q.png)